# How to trim figures using PyLatex

Tags: python, latex, figure

I know that in Latex you could use `\includegraphics[clip, trim={x x x x}]{image.jpg}` to trim a image, but I don't know how to do this in PyLatex. I tried

```
from pylatex import Document, Figure
from pylatex.base_classes.command import Options

doc=Document()
doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as fig:
    fig.add_image(image.jpg, Options('clip', width=50, trim='0 2cm 0 2cm'))
```

but it does not let me do it. The `add_image`function seems to only takes the file name, the width and position. I wonder if there's anyway to use PyLatex to trim my figure, or do I need to define my own command to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_image` is not very flexible, but you can create and append `StandAloneGraphic`:

```
from pylatex import Document, Figure, StandAloneGraphic
from pylatex.base_classes.command import Options
from pylatex.utils import fix_filename

doc=Document()
doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as fig:
    fig.append(
        StandAloneGraphic(
            image_options=Options('clip', width=50, trim='0 2cm 0 2cm'),
            filename=fix_filename('image.jpg')))
```